# java line breaks in file

Tags: java, apache, file

I am trying to write a file line by line using apache FileUtils.writeLines()
When I try to open the file (notepad++, editplus) it is with no line breaks.
(I am sending null to the encoding)
thanks.

```
FileUtils.writeLines(new File(INDICES_AND_WEIGHTS_FILENAME), indicesAndWeightsParams.indicesParams,";");
```

where indicesParams is a list
  public List indicesParams;

Comment: how do you write line break ?

Comment: We aren't psychic; show the code. We can't tell you what's wrong with it if we can't see it.

Comment: It works if you call the method with the correct arguments.  Show us your actual code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using code similar to this?

```
List<String> ls = new ArrayList<String>();
ls.add("aaa");
ls.add("bbbbb");

FileUtils.writeLines(new File("newfile.txt"), "UTF-8", ls);   // same effect as with "null" as encoding
```

After this code, `newFile.txt` does have newlines.

Using `od -a newfile.txt` generates (on Windows):

```
0000000   a   a   a  cr  nl   b   b   b   b   b  cr  nl
0000014
```

which shows that newlines really do exist.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure which version of `writeLines()` you're calling. There is one version which allows you to specify the line endings. If you pass an empty string there, you won't get any:

```
public static void writeLines(File file, Collection<String> lines, String lineEnding) throws IOException {
```

The encoding is always between the file and the collection, the line separator is always the last parameter.

Comment: Well, you set the line separator to ";" -- what do you expect?

Comment: You should set it to whatever you want between the lines; that's what it is for.

Answer (score 1):

Just add "\r\n" where ever you want the breaks.

Comment: but I want it automatically. thats why it saves a